# pageViews in Application Insights stop getting logged when registering an auth scheme with a default scheme in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

My Asp.Net Core app has been correctly logging into requests and pageViews in Application Insights.

However, when I do this it stops logging pageViews (although requests are logged):

```
  services.AddAuthentication("MyScheme");
```

But, note that if I do this (not specify a default scheme) like this then pageViews are logging fine:

```
  services.AddAuthentication();
```

Can someone explain how AddAuthentication with a default scheme is interfering with pageViews logging?

EDIT: The "MyScheme" I have specified as default uses a JWT Bearer auth scheme against accounts setup in AzureAD.

Also, I use [ASP.NET Core App Monitoring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-core?tabs=netcorenew%2Cnetcore6) to log into App Insights.

Comment: What is the .NET Core version you are using ?

Comment: Can you please share your complete `Program.cs` file.

Comment: This is on .NET 6. I have a whole lot going on in the Program.cs file, lot of private info, not sure if I can share.

Comment: Have you checked the below sol.

Comment: Yea, I see it works for you, but it doesn't for me. One thing to note is that this Auth scheme I use is set to authorize users against accounts setup in Azure AD. That is in fact an important information I should have mentioned earlier, my bad. I am updating the description now.

Comment: Yes..even I am authenticating the app with AD.You can see my appsettings.json client secrets.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to log Pageview for my WebApp even after registering auth scheme with a default scheme.

When I try to access with

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
```

I am getting the below error

```cs
InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
```

I have set the Authentication Scheme as below

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
```

***Check the below Workaround to configure ApplicationInsights and log Pageviews***

I am able to log both Locally and from the Deployed Azure App service.

I have referred  [Microsoft Application Insights JavaScript SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript-sdk?tabs=javascriptwebsdkloaderscript#add-the-javascript-code) to log Page Views.

In  `_ViewStart.cshtml` file, under `Views` folder write the below script.

```cs
<script type="text/javascript">
    !(function (cfg) { function e() { cfg.onInit && cfg.onInit(i) } var S, u, D, t, n, i, C = window, x = document, w = C.location, I = "script", b = "ingestionendpoint", E = "disableExceptionTracking", A = "ai.device."; "instrumentationKey"[S = "toLowerCase"](), u = "crossOrigin", D = "POST", t = "appInsightsSDK", n = cfg.name || "appInsights", (cfg.name || C[t]) && (C[t] = n), i = C[n] || function (l) { var d = !1, g = !1, f = { initialize: !0, queue: [], sv: "7", version: 2, config: l }; function m(e, t) { var n = {}, i = "Browser"; function a(e) { e = "" + e; return 1 === e.length ? "0" + e : e } return n[A + "id"] = i[S](), n[A + "type"] = i, n["ai.operation.name"] = w && w.pathname || "_unknown_", n["ai.internal.sdkVersion"] = "javascript:snippet_" + (f.sv || f.version), { time: (i = new Date).getUTCFullYear() + "-" + a(1 + i.getUTCMonth()) + "-" + a(i.getUTCDate()) + "T" + a(i.getUTCHours()) + ":" + a(i.getUTCMinutes()) + ":" + a(i.getUTCSeconds()) + "." + (i.getUTCMilliseconds() / 1e3).toFixed(3).slice(2, 5) + "Z", iKey: e, name: "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights." + e.replace(/-/g, "") + "." + t, sampleRate: 100, tags: n, data: { baseData: { ver: 2 } }, ver: 4, seq: "1", aiDataContract: undefined } } var h = -1, v = 0, y = ["js.monitor.azure.com", "js.cdn.applicationinsights.io", "js.cdn.monitor.azure.com", "js0.cdn.applicationinsights.io", "js0.cdn.monitor.azure.com", "js2.cdn.applicationinsights.io", "js2.cdn.monitor.azure.com", "az416426.vo.msecnd.net"], k = l.url || cfg.src; if (k) { if ((n = navigator) && (~(n = (n.userAgent || "").toLowerCase()).indexOf("msie") || ~n.indexOf("trident/")) && ~k.indexOf("ai.3") && (k = k.replace(/(\/)(ai\.3\.)([^\d]*)$/, function (e, t, n) { return t + "ai.2" + n })), !1 !== cfg.cr) for (var e = 0; e < y.length; e++)if (0 < k.indexOf(y[e])) { h = e; break } var i = function (e) { var a, t, n, i, o, r, s, c, p, u; f.queue = [], g || (0 <= h && v + 1 < y.length ? (a = (h + v + 1) % y.length, T(k.replace(/^(.*\/\/)([\w\.]*)(\/.*)$/, function (e, t, n, i) { return t + y[a] + i })), v += 1) : (d = g = !0, o = k, c = (p = function () { var e, t = {}, n = l.connectionString; if (n) for (var i = n.split(";"), a = 0; a < i.length; a++) { var o = i[a].split("="); 2 === o.length && (t[o[0][S]()] = o[1]) } return t[b] || (e = (n = t.endpointsuffix) ? t.location : null, t[b] = "https://" + (e ? e + "." : "") + "dc." + (n || "services.visualstudio.com")), t }()).instrumentationkey || l.instrumentationKey || "", p = (p = p[b]) ? p + "/v2/track" : l.endpointUrl, (u = []).push((t = "SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details)", n = o, r = p, (s = (i = m(c, "Exception")).data).baseType = "ExceptionData", s.baseData.exceptions = [{ typeName: "SDKLoadFailed", message: t.replace(/\./g, "-"), hasFullStack: !1, stack: t + "\nSnippet failed to load [" + n + "] -- Telemetry is disabled\nHelp Link: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2128109\nHost: " + (w && w.pathname || "_unknown_") + "\nEndpoint: " + r, parsedStack: [] }], i)), u.push((s = o, t = p, (r = (n = m(c, "Message")).data).baseType = "MessageData", (i = r.baseData).message = 'AI (Internal): 99 message:"' + ("SDK LOAD Failure: Failed to load Application Insights SDK script (See stack for details) (" + s + ")").replace(/\"/g, "") + '"', i.properties = { endpoint: t }, n)), o = u, c = p, JSON && ((r = C.fetch) && !cfg.useXhr ? r(c, { method: D, body: JSON.stringify(o), mode: "cors" }) : XMLHttpRequest && ((s = new XMLHttpRequest).open(D, c), s.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json"), s.send(JSON.stringify(o)))))) }, a = function (e, t) { g || setTimeout(function () { !t && f.core || i() }, 500), d = !1 }, T = function (e) { var n = x.createElement(I), e = (n.src = e, cfg[u]); return !e && "" !== e || "undefined" == n[u] || (n[u] = e), n.onload = a, n.onerror = i, n.onreadystatechange = function (e, t) { "loaded" !== n.readyState && "complete" !== n.readyState || a(0, t) }, cfg.ld && cfg.ld < 0 ? x.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(n) : setTimeout(function () { x.getElementsByTagName(I)[0].parentNode.appendChild(n) }, cfg.ld || 0), n }; T(k) } try { f.cookie = x.cookie } catch (p) { } function t(e) { for (; e.length;)!function (t) { f[t] = function () { var e = arguments; d || f.queue.push(function () { f[t].apply(f, e) }) } }(e.pop()) } var r, s, n = "track", o = "TrackPage", c = "TrackEvent", n = (t([n + "Event", n + "PageView", n + "Exception", n + "Trace", n + "DependencyData", n + "Metric", n + "PageViewPerformance", "start" + o, "stop" + o, "start" + c, "stop" + c, "addTelemetryInitializer", "setAuthenticatedUserContext", "clearAuthenticatedUserContext", "flush"]), f.SeverityLevel = { Verbose: 0, Information: 1, Warning: 2, Error: 3, Critical: 4 }, (l.extensionConfig || {}).ApplicationInsightsAnalytics || {}); return !0 !== l[E] && !0 !== n[E] && (t(["_" + (r = "onerror")]), s = C[r], C[r] = function (e, t, n, i, a) { var o = s && s(e, t, n, i, a); return !0 !== o && f["_" + r]({ message: e, url: t, lineNumber: n, columnNumber: i, error: a, evt: C.event }), o }, l.autoExceptionInstrumented = !0), f }(cfg.cfg), (C[n] = i).queue && 0 === i.queue.length ? (i.queue.push(e), i.trackPageView({})) : e(); })({
        src: "https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.3.gbl.min.js",
      
        crossOrigin: "anonymous",       
        cfg: { 
            connectionString: "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://**********.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://**********.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
        }
    });
</script>
```

- Replace the Connection String with yours.
- In `_Layout.cshtml` page add the below line in `<head>` tag.

```cs
@Html.Raw(JavaScriptSnippet.FullScript)
```

***My `appsettings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "**********.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "**********",
    "ClientId": "**********",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://australiacentral-0.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://australiacentral.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

***Output:***
[image]

### Update

As you have mentioned in the comments,Yes I have added Azure AD authentication and Configured Application Insights for my WebApp.

[image]

- Change the appsettings.json file as shown above.
- Add the below line of code in `Program.cs` file

```cs
builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(builder.Configuration["APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING"]);
```

Comment: FYI, one key difference between yours and mine is that I use the ASP.NET Core App Monitoring approach to log - updated description.

Comment: Yes I have configured application Insights from connected services.On top of it added Javascript to log page views.you can see the application Insights connection string in configuration file.

Comment: Change the logging configuration as shown above you can see the logs.

Comment: @cooper_milton - Please check the updated section in the posted answer.

Comment: Please share your complete program.cs file by removing your private info.